# Tab bar application with UINavigation Controller MOC not being retained

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, tabbar

I created a tab bar application from the template and added a navigation controller to one of the tabs. I have already created this app from the navigation app template already and is working. The reason I am doing it this way is because I need to add a tab bar and thought it would be easier starting by using the tab bar project template and adding the nav controller to it rather than the other way round.

I have copied the data model over from the other project and added the relevant code to where it should be.

The problem I am having is passing the `moc` from the app delegate to the tab with the nav controller on. Here is a snippet from my `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method in my app delegate:

```
(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
[self createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded];



Top_BananaTableViewController *top_BananaTableViewController = (Top_BananaTableViewController *)[navigationController topViewController];

top_BananaTableViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;



// Add the tab bar controller's current view as a subview of the window
[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Everything seems fine here but when it comes to the `fetchedResultsController` on my nav controller view it bombs out with:

> +entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity
>   name 'cards'

When I checked what was set to my `managedObjectContext` on that view it was `null`.

I don't know why or where it is loosing it's setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Top_BananaTableViewController *top_BananaTableViewController =
 (Top_BananaTableViewController *)[navigationController topViewController];
```

My guess is that either `navigationController` is `nil` here, or the returned value from calling the `topViewController` method is `nil`.

Comment: I have resolved this by placing:

 Top_BananaAppDelegate *appDelegate = (Top_BananaAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    self.managedObjectContext =  appDelegate.managedObjectContext;

in the viewdidload method of TopBananaTableViewController

Answer (score 0):

"+entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'cards'" is because you don't have a valid MOC reference.